# Plot VoronoiDiagram with different Norms

Tags: graph, wolfram-mathematica, voronoi

I got a big prob with mathematica(using version 8).
Plotting a Voronoi Diagram is simple stuff, but how about changing the norm?

```
<< DiscreteMath`ComputationalGeometry`
data2D = {{4.4, 14}, {6.7, 15.25}, {6.9, 12.8}, {2.1, 11.1}, {9.5, 
14.9}, {13.2, 11.9}, {10.3, 12.3}, {6.8, 9.5}, {3.3, 7.7}, {0.6, 
5.1}, {5.3, 2.4}, {8.45, 4.7}, {11.5, 9.6}, {13.8, 7.3}, {12.9, 
3.1}, {11, 1.1}};
DiagramPlot[data2D, LabelPoints -> False]
```

Gives me the Voronoi Diagram respective to the L_2-norm(euclidean norm).
I am needing the Diagram respective to the L_1-norm and the L_infinity-norm as well...

Comment: A quick look through the code (in v.7) shows that the norms are implemented by hand, not using `Norm`. If it was using `Norm`, you could override it by wrapping your code in `Block[{Norm = <new norm>}, ...]`.

Comment: Yep. It seems you'll need to roll your own

Comment: I will, if I know how... I did not get what u mean...

Comment: If `DiagramPlot`, and its constituents, used `Norm`, you could have used `Block` to override the behavior because it allows you to create a local definition of an existing symbol. However, internally they use the form `Sqrt[ (a1-b1)^2 + (a2 - b2)^2 + (a3 - b3)^2]`, not `Norm`, so you can't simply override the behavior. Instead, you'll have to re-implement the code to accept differing norms, hence the term: "roll your own."

Comment: Means, I have to program my own "DiagramPlot"-Funktion with different Norms? I found this [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiImage/) on their HP, so i hope(d) that there is an easier way...

Comment: Essentially, yes. An option is to take the existing code, and modify it. This can be treacherous, though, as you may not wholly understand the existing code.

Comment: I found this [link](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiImage/) on their HP, so i hope(d) that there is an easier way... Where can I find/get the code(from DiagramPlot)?

Comment: Looking at the code from the demonstration, shows that it's not using `DiagramPlot` at all, but [`DistanceTransform`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DistanceTransform.html) plotted by `ReliefPlot`. To get the code for `DiagramPlot` look under `$InstallationDirectory/AddOns/Packages`.

Comment: Kann sein. Das muss doch eigentlich einfacher gehen... Danke nochmal wegen dem Code des `DiagramPlot`. Habs mir eben mal angeschaut, schlau bin ich aber bisher nicht daraus geworden.

Comment: Sie sollten in Englisch zu schreiben

Comment: @belisarius Close, no need for 'zu' here

Comment: @Sjoerd Thanks! My last German lesson was a few centuries ago, so no surprise in my mistake (as a matter of fact I've used Google Translate because I was unable to do it on my own)

Comment: @belisarius My last lesson was 32 years ago, so it's not too fresh for me either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Mma help](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WatershedComponents.html) (only an approximation):

[image]

[image]

```
ColorCombine[{Image[ WatershedComponents[
    DistanceTransform[i, DistanceFunction -> ManhattanDistance]], 
    "Bit"], i, i}]
```

[image]

NB: Please note that the convexity property for the Voronoi polygon is lost ...

Comment: @rcollyer I just upgraded for 75 bucks... Worth seeing if you can get your advisor to pay for it

Comment: @yoda, its my machine, so I'd feel bad for installing it. Have to check out what's deals IT has as they have a lot of student/faculty deals, of which I think mma is included.